# OpenJDK 7 Installation trouble on 10.04

Tags: java, openjdk

I added the following common personal package archive as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

The update goes well, but when I try to install the `openjdk-7-jdk` it stops with an unmet dependency on the `openjdk-7-jre`.  So, not sure what is going on, I chase the unmet dependencies down to these two (note: lib depends on headless), so I try to install them together:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-lib openjdk-7-jre-headless
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  openjdk-7-jre-headless: Conflicts: openjdk-7-jre-lib (< 7b89~pre1-0) but 7~b117~pre1-0lucid1 is to be installed
  openjdk-7-jre-lib: Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (>= 7b89~pre1) but 7~b117~pre1-0lucid1 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: openjdk-7-jre-headless (< 7b89~pre1-0) but 7~b117~pre1-0lucid1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Now, I'm really lost.  Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: And also post the output of `uname -r`.

Comment: **Note**: [Desktop 10.04 is EOL, the server version is supported till April 2015](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: `blade`, yes maybe I belong on debian..

Comment: is that server version or desktop version?

Comment: `-f` just reports some c++ libraries that are not required but I would like to keep. The kernel is 2.6.32-51-generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add these to your sources.list file

```
 deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
 deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
```

then

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
```

and finally

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

if you just want java compiler then download one from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html) accept and download it
then open terminal and install it

```
sudo sh jdk-7u51-nb-7_4-linux-ixxx.sh
```

and follow these [steps](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Comment: Sorry about that but thanks for the heads up. got it

Comment: I did see it download the `oneiric/partner` packages and source.  I attempted the various `install` commands again but they all had the same results.

Comment: use these                                                      (deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk/ppa/ubuntu lucid main)
(deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk/ppa/ubuntu lucid main)

Comment: details are at launchpad.net

Comment: @Olupot... I am using the launchpad lucid entries to no avail.

Comment: @jcalfee314 my best option would be for you to just download the oracle jdk (as a shell script bundled with netbeans) and install it locally. It's actually a very good option. Visit Oracle and get that file